# Printing table data scraped and parsed using lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

i am trying to print the data in the form of something like pandas data frame, but i don,t know extract information from .

```
import requests

response=requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_advanced.html')

# print(response.text)

doc = lh.fromstring(response.content)

tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

print(tr_elements[0])
```

============OUTPUT==========

```
<Element tr at 0x3f7ccf0>
```

Comment: `print(lh.tostring(tr_elements[0]).decode())` will show the html string your element has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to know exactly what you are trying to achieve but the following will take the table data you have and create a data frame with column names based on the table headers and then the data populated without the repeating table header rows.

```
import lxml.html as lh
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_advanced.html')
doc = lh.fromstring(response.content)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
headers = [header.text for header in tr_elements[0]] //get the table headers
rows = []
for element in tr_elements[1:]:
    row = [data.text for data in element]  //get the non nested table elements
    if row[1] is None:
        row[1] = element[1][0].text // get player name from hyper link
        if not isinstance(row[4], str):
            row[4] = element[4][0].text //get team name from hyper link
        rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
df.columns = headers
print(df)
```